# Observable in angular 2 ?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I searched and explored regarding my question but I didn't get the appropriate answer, I am new in angular 2, exploring and creating a demo app with the help of angular's official doc. ( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html ). Now I reached HTTP section. Here I am not able to understand what is observable and why it is used?

Can anyone please let me know why Observable used in below code?

```
search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http
               .get(`app/heroes/?name=${term}`)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
  }
```

why here also  ?:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
}
```

**I am still confused for promise and observable . What is the difference between promise and observable ? And why they chose Observable ?**

Comment: That answer covered some aspect of my question but not all part.

Comment: Are you asking why and what is an Observable.. Or are you asking what's the difference between a promise and an Observable, and why did they chose for Observable?

Comment: Yes i am asking for why did they chose for Observable ?